# Why cant i replace the character at 0th index with character at 1th index through the assignment statement at line 11?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
char d;
char *r="Helloo";
printf("%s\n",r);

d=*(r+1);
printf("%c",d);

*(r+0)=d;

printf("%s\n",r);

}
```

> this was working fine when i stored the string in a character array but why doesn't it work now

Comment: `"Helloo"`, the string `r` points to, is read-only; try `char r[] = "Helloo";` instead (array vs pointer -- they're different).

Comment: Please write `r[1]` and `r[0]` instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *r="Helloo";
```

You assigned pointer `r` to a string literal. String literals should be treated as immutable. Any attempt to modify one leads to undefined behavior (N1570, Section 6.4.5/7).

With

```
char r[]="Helloo";
```

You have the string stored in an array that you *can* modify so it works as expected.

Comment: Are C string laterals *necessarily* immutable, or is that implementation dependant?

Comment: @ScottHunter It depends on the implementation. The standard only says modifying string literals has undefined behavior, so portable code must treat them as immutable. But then that's what *immutable* means in general: You try to modify it, you get UB.

Comment: OK, but dictionary definition of *immutable* makes it sound like the string *can't* be modified, even if you tried (which is the behavior that led to the question), whereas the "C" definition sounds like there are no guarantees as to what happens if you try.  A distinction the person asking the question might not be aware of (and might not even care).

Comment: @ScottHunter Yeah I understand that. Jonathan's edit makes this clear. (thanks Jonathan!)